# What is an efficient way to replace specific columns with a subset in pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I already asked this question a while ago but in a different context, yet that method is too time-consuming. currently, my code takes 12 seconds for one epoch.

I need to apply a mask on specific columns of a tensor. I could not find any helping function for that, so I am creating a subset and then applying the mask on the subset. Now I need to merge the subset into the original tensor but I can not find an efficient way.

```
python
import torch
X=torch.rand(10,9) 
tensorsize = X.size()
indices = torch.tensor([0,3,7,5,4])  #sorting them will make the process faster?
candidateCF=torch.index_select(X,1,indices)
mask=torch.FloatTensor(candidateCF.size()).uniform_() >= 0.3
output=candidateCF.mul(mask)
print(output)
```

The above code is fine, `output` is masked tensor.

Now I need to replace this `output` tensor into `X`. What could be a most efficient way to do that.

**Or**

There is any method to directly mask the X's specific columns? I think it would be more efficient.

Note: to clarify, `output will be a subset of X`

Comment: Running your code throws `RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [10, 5] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [5, 9]`

Comment: i have clarified my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, posting, it may help others.

```
X[:, indices] = output # for column replacements
X[indices, :] = output # for row replacements
```